# access paypal response in ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, response

I have abort like

```
abort(response.payment_info.inspect)
```

and the response is like

```
[#<Paypal::Payment::Response::Info:0x007f25f62a8410 @ack="Success", @currency_code="USD", @error_code="0", @order_time="2015-07-01T13:30:54Z", @payment_status="Completed", @payment_type="instant", @pending_reason="None", @protection_eligibility="Ineligible", @protection_eligibility_type="None", @reason_code="None", @receipt_id=nil, @secure_merchant_account_id="XPN8GAK2PGVCQ", @transaction_id="63H82632FA7502700", @transaction_type="expresscheckout", @request_id=nil, @seller_id=nil, @exchange_rate=nil, @amount=#<Paypal::Payment::Common::Amount:0x007f25f629f400 @total=5, @item=0, @fee=0.5, @handing=0, @insurance=0, @ship_disc=0, @shipping=0, @tax=0, @gross=0, @net=0>>]
```

How can I get the transaction_id or other variables like amount?
Please help me out this.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found. We can do like this.

```
response.payment_info.first.transaction_id
response.payment_info.first.payment_status
response.payment_info.first.amount.total
```